# Tuning a PID Controller

Tags: matlab, filter-design, transfer-function, control-systems, pid

I have the following transfer function
$$10000 \cdot\frac{(s-0.012)(s+1.05)(s-18)}{(s+0.22)^2(s+45)(s+1000)}$$
For which I am trying to tune a PID controller for. I'm using the pidTuner in MATLAB to do so. I wish to have the settle time be less than 3 seconds if possible, however, the best I have been able to do is 77 seconds with the settings $K_p = 0.049955$, $K_i = 0.0087525$ and $K_d=0$. At these values, going in any direction seems to increase the settling time more. Any help would be really great!

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 right-half plane zeroes : 0.012 and 18. The zero at +18 is "fast" and will not affect the performance much, but your slow zero at 0.012 will severely limit your performance. You can't cancel this right-half plane zero with a right-half plane pole in your controller, your controller output will be unbounded.

Is this homework or a real life problem?

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is for school. If that's the case then is there anything I can do? This transfer function seems to model the system quite well.

Comment: Would a controller other than a PID controller work better?

Comment: I doubt it. The slow RHP zero is probably the limiting factor. Maybe you made a mistake in your transfer function ? How did you obtain it?

Comment: Estimated poles and zeros off of a Bode plot, then used the bode function in MATLAB to guess and check the signs of the zeros until the bode plots matched each other.

Comment: what if you change (s-0.012) for (s + 0.012) ?

Comment: Gave it a shot, the phase plot no longer lines up and when running a step function through it, it settles at -1 instead of +1.

Comment: Did your Bode plot frequency range extend down to 1 milli-Hz (i.e., the speed of that slow unstable zero)?  If not, it could be a phantom.  Do you have a step response for the system as well as a Bode plot?  Checking your transfer function's step response against the actual system's step response should be informative.

Comment: @TimWescott here is a plot of the step response for both the system as well as the transfer function: https://postimg.cc/mzyS8rV9. As you can see, they are very similar, so I believe the transfer function models the system well.

Comment: Ohh, yes.  That's nasty.  That sharp initial negative response, followed by a slow increase to a positive response is the time-domain manifestation of your slow unstable zero.  You are not going to have an easy time controlling that for a fast, precise response.  It's not within the bounds of your question but -- can you change the plant?  Part of the **real** job of a control systems engineer is to inform the mechanical team -- diplomatically or with the use of clue-by-fours -- that they need to change things.

Comment: Since this is homework, you could validate with your prof if the experimental step response is to be expected or if there's been a mistake somwhere.